# Copy URL from simulator's safari and Paste to Mac

Tags: ios-simulator

I want to copy a URL from simulator's safari app and paste it outside in my mac. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy from Mac OS X does not copy to iPhone Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604478/copy-from-mac-os-x-does-not-copy-to-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was already [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604478/copy-from-mac-os-x-does-not-copy-to-iphone-simulator). You can use Copy and Paste Options in the Edit Menu from the Simulator in OS X. They let you share the contents of the system clipboard and the simulator clipboard.

I flagged the question as duplicate.

Comment: I am able to copy the URL using simulator's touch-based SelectAll, Copy. However, I cannot paste it to my Mac's Xcode. Paste is not highlighted.