# Xcode simulator - copy/paste issue

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I've been having this issue for quite sometime now. Basically, when I cannot copy something from my web browser or a file and paste it into the simulator (ie in an `UITextField` for example). I read multiple questions here, I tried the suggested answers, but nothing works really.

When I copy something from my web browser for example, I have `Automatically Sync Pasteboard` activated in my simulator and yet, cmd + V doesn't paste it. Even though I've copied the data, I have no `edit > paste` menu activated in my  simulator. Even if I disable `Automatically Sync Pasteboard`, I dont get the `edit > paste` menu. I'm testing this on iPhone 8 simulator.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Same here. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sadly, no. Just started using my phone instead of the simulator when I had to paste something. Which is no solution at all

Comment: I realized that if I write any text in the text field and select it, the option to paste shows up! It's a weird "solution", but it's working for me.

Comment: Yes, but the point is to be able to copy/paste large chunks of text from a web browser or a text document and just paste it in the simulator. Which doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was having the same problem.

I turned the Automatic Pasteboard Sync off and on again and it started working.

Comment: My simulators must hate me because that also doesn't work lol I tried doing it multiple times and nothing really

Comment: This ended up working for me. Note, however, that after toggling the feature, you need to copy again before attempting to paste.

Comment: It finally worked. I tried this so many times and it didn't work. But now it does. I haven't tried something different. No idea why it happened like that

Comment: Just turn off Auto Pasteboard Sync, then do manual Get and Send actions (in the same dropdown menu)

Answer (score 0):

I searched for an answer for this for some time. For Apple Silicon (M1) I eventually found a [page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74970) where some users had tracked it down to an issue with iOS 14+. When I installed switched to a simulator iOS 13.7 as instructed (see [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74970)) pasting worked again. While this is clearly not what was going on with the original question (10 years ago!), I am pasting here in case someone else has this issue.

Copied from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70206587/3341148).