# Cannot paste text on mac into ios simulator Xcode 12?

Tags: xcode, xamarin, ios-simulator

I am using Xcode 12.5, and I am trying to paste some text from a file into my ios Simulator **(iPhone 11 ios 14.5)**. This does not work. Any thoughts or ideas on how to fix this?

I have looked at a number of other posts but they all seem outdated and don't work for me.

Also I am using an Apple M1 Mac mini ...if that makes a difference. I am also building my application with Xamarin.

The steps I took:

- I turn of **Automatically Sync Pasteboard**
- Copy the text (which is just letters from a .txt file)
- Click **send pasteboard** from the edit menu.
- Click on my **Editor** control and select **paste**

The outcome is that it shows the bubble at the top saying `myappName pasted from CoreSimulatorBridge`. However, it doesn't actually paste the text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188852/copy-paste-text-into-ios-simulator

Comment: @Jason this is old and does not work

Comment: I am able to copy text from the desktop and paste into the simulator without issue

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? and what device?

Comment: latest XCode, iOS 14.5, you have to tap an entry and hold until the paste button appears, or disable auto sync and use "send pasteboard" from the Edit menu

Comment: I have just tried this and it doesn't work for me. It shows the bubble at the top saying  myappName pasted from CoreSimulatorBridge. However, it doesn't actually paste the text. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to paste?  And into what kind of control?

Comment: I have updated the question to answer your questions

Comment: @Kikanye  I follow your steps to test, it works fine, but I don't use Apple M1 Mac mini, if you still have this problem, I suggest you can go to github to feedback this question.

Answer (score 4):

I answered this [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70206587/3341148), but it took so long to find I am repasting a couple places I looked first. Essentially, with Apple M1 Silicon, iOS 14+ pasting doesn't work. Switching to a simulator running 13.7 or earlier fixed it.

Comment: Hopefully someone has filed a radar.

Answer (score 0):

it seems it was an issue that Apple fixed in the latest XCode updates, copy/paste works with me on a simulator with IOS 16.2 and XCode 14.2

Answer (score -2):

Now with XCode 14 I'm not being able to build 13.7 or earlier.

Comment: Be more specific about the question

Comment: Answer not relevant to the question

Comment: What do you mean?